# Ubuntu server cannot power off

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

I have a problem with my Ubuntu Server.
If I type:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

There are many logs and in the end it says reboot: Power down.

And after 30 seconds, the computer reboots.

I run Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS on a iMac Retina from the end of 2015.

And maybe the information is helpful:
I have physical access to the computer.

I don't know how I can fix this.

Can anybody help me?

In the log-file there is the following error:

```
systemd-networkd.socket: Failed to queue service startup job (Maybe the service file is missing or not a non-template unit?): Transaction for systemd-networkd.service/start is destructive (systemd-poweroff.service has 'start' job queue not a non-template unit?): Transaction for systemd-networkd.service/start is destructive (systemd-poweroff.service has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction).
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more details. Is this a desktop computer? A server rig? A laptop? A virtual machine? What version of Ubuntu are you using? Do you have physical access to the machine?

Comment: Can you share the log?

Comment: Look at `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` (`-b -1` is "previous boot, `‐e` is "end of log", read `man journalctl`) and look for "`timeout`", or timestamps with large intervals between entries.